# Can Minecraft PE texture pack purchased on phone be unlocked also on our tablet?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

...since it's the same PE account on both devices, because the same Google account is on both. Wondered if there was also a way to "share" the purchased texture packs purchased in the minecraft store? Both are android. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, looks like it fixed itself -- after 48 hours the purchased packs are showing up on both devices -- must have updated itself. Couldn't find a "Restore" button, but thanks to Luiyay anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Buy the texture pack and on the other device use the "Restore" button.